# How to use a member function for diferent objects of same class

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have created a vector of classes using a for, and initializing the member variables from a .txt like this

```
ifstream  fitxer(fichero);

if (fitxer.is_open())
{

int = 0;

delete[] m_Clase; //m_Clase is a pointer declared in main.h

m_Clase = new CClass [10];

for (i=0; i<10; i++){

  is >> m_Clase[i];
}

fitxer.close();
}
```

And i have a member function of the class CClass, that returns an int:

```
int
CClass::Suma (int X, int Y){

total = X + Y;

return total;
}
```

The vector then has 10 'CClass' classes, with a 'suma' fucntion each one. So I would like to get the total result from adding every 'suma' function, but i dont know how to do it. I imgine it would be something like this:

```
int resultado = 0;
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
resultado = resultado + m_Clase.Suma[i];
}
```

but it doesnt work.

Comment: Your `Suma` function requires two parameters (X and Y), yet your code doesn't pass it any parameters.

Comment: Your code has very basic errors. Getting an answer to the specific problems won't help you in the long run. I suggest working through the problems in a good text book.

Comment: The code it was just an exemple, and it was not complete. Im just starting in C++ tho and my sintaxy is horrible. But i have reached the answer already, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resultado += m_Clase [i].Suma ();
```

This is assuming Suma uses member functions, otherwise why bother having it in the class? If it uses non member variables, you could just make it a static function an not worry about which instance is being called:

```
resultado += CClass::Suma (X, Y);
```